# How to save a dish with an onion paste base which tastes like raw onion paste?

Tags: onions

I was making a dish that requires the use of onion paste. Usually I'd fry the paste, but I had a bunch of other stuff that needed to be fried too, so I put that in first, and I guess by the time I added the onion paste there wasn't much oil left and it didn't get fried. Now the dish tastes too oniony, and is almost unpalatable. I thought I could fix it by boiling the hell out of it, as onion turns sweet when you boil it - it was a long shot, but I was desperate. That didn't help.

This is what I did -

Fried some ginger garlic paste, and then put in one chopped tomato. After the tomatoes softened I added the onion paste, and then some cashew paste. Maybe I put in the cashew paste too early. Anyway, that is the base of the dish. After a while I added some water and seasoned it. When I tasted it, it tasted only of onions. Nothing really helped - added more water, cooked the hell outta it.

Is there any way I can save the dish? Maybe heat up some oil in another wok and upturn the dish into it?

Comment: can you give us more details on what the dish is and what it contains? that might help us to give you a good answer..

Comment: @DhariniChandrasekaran edited the question.

Comment: How many onions did you use?

Comment: 3 or 4 medium sized ones. Don't think that was the issue though, as I have used these many before

Comment: Secondly, can name the dish which you were making?

Comment: A variation of Shahi Paneer, but don't think that matters

Comment: It matters because people here can suggest you how to save "Shahi Paneer" by maybe adding or subtracting something.

Comment: Don't want to start an argument here, but since I have described what I have done in making the base/gravy, and that is all I have done, don't think naming the dish would do much, other than attract attention of people who know the dish, which, while helpful in getting more people to open the question, doesn't change much functionally. I could just as easily make Dum Aloo with the same base.

Comment: I'd throw it out and start again. It's only a few onions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess my first instinct to heat some oil and fry it off was correct.

Had the base in the fridge and instead of throwing it away thought I'd try it out, and it worked.

Though there was still a hint of raw onion paste, it wasn't as bad as earlier, and could taste the other ingredients too.